# vb. net input border in print preview

Tags: vb.net

I would like to ask on how to put a border in print preview and it will also put the label value inside the border please see attached print preview screenshot thank you. Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
[print preview screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8YQA.png)

here is my code:

```
 Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(sender As Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage



    e.Graphics.DrawString("CONOLOSCOPY", New Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Red, New Point(300, 20))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("ENDOSCOPY NO.: " + txt_ID.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 60))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(180, 60))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("REG NO.: " + txt_REGNO.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(300, 60))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(390, 60))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("HEIGHT: " + txt_HEIGHT.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(500, 60))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(580, 60))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("DATE: " + txt_DATE.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 80))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("______________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(70, 80))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("ROOM NO.: " + txt_ROOMNO.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(280, 80))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(380, 80))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("WEIGHT NO.: " + txt_WEIGHT.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(500, 80))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(620, 80))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("LAST NAME: " + txt_LNAME.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 130))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("__________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(120, 130))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("FIRST NAME: " + txt_FNAME.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(350, 130))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("__________________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(470, 130))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("AGE: " + txt_AGE.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 160))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_____", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(55, 160))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("SEX: " + txt_SEX.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(120, 160))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_____", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(170, 160))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("CELL NO.: " + txt_CELLNO.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(250, 160))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(340, 160))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("ADDRESS: " + txt_ADDRESS.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 190))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("__________________________________________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(100, 190))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("EMAIL: " + txt_EMAIL.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 240))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_______________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(60, 240))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("REFERRING MD: " + txt_REFERMD.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 270))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(160, 270))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("ATTENDING MD: " + txt_MD.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(350, 270))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("___________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(495, 270))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("ANESTHESIOLOGIST: " + txt_ANES.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 300))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_______________________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(210, 300))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("PROCEDURE: " + txt_PROC.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 330))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("______________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(135, 330))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("INDICATION: " + txt_INDICATION.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(350, 330))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(460, 330))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("PREMEDICATION: " + txt_PREMED.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 360))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_______________________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(170, 360))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("SCOPE USED: " + txt_SCOPE.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 390))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("___________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(140, 390))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("PROCTIME: " + txt_PROCTIME.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(400, 390))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("___________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(510, 390))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("BIOPSY: " + txt_BIOPSY.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(370, 420))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("___________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(450, 420))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("ESOPHAGUS: " + txt_ESOPHAGUS.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 450))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("CARDIA: " + txt_CARDIA.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 480))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("BODY: " + txt_BODY.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 510))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("ANTRUM: " + txt_ANTRUM.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 540))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("DUODENAL: " + txt_DUODENAL.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 580))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("ENDOSCOPIC DESCRIPTION: " + txt_ENDODESC.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 610))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_________________________________________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(270, 610))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("THERAPEUTIC INTERVENTION " + txt_THERAPEUTIC.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 660))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("______________________________________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(290, 660))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("DIAGNOSIS: " + txt_DIAGNOSIS.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 810))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("___________________________________________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(120, 810))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("HISTOPATH: " + txt_HISTOPATH.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 960))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_______________________________________________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(120, 960))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("ENDOSCOPIST: " + txt_ENDOSPCOPIST.Text, New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(10, 1010))
    e.Graphics.DrawString("_______________________________________________________", New Font("Arial", 13, FontStyle.Regular), Brushes.Black, New Point(150, 1010))






End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at the other members of that `Graphics` class, besides `DrawString`. You can draw anything you want, however you want. You should already know this because you should have already done that research.

Comment: By the way, why do you keep creating new `Font` objects over and over when they all have the same properties? Create one `Font` object per set of properties and assign them to variables, then use those variables as required, then dispose the `Font` objects. As always, you should use a `Using` statement to create such objects, so they are implicitly disposed at the end of the block.

Comment: Also, did you mean "COLONOSCOPY" rather than "CONOLOSCOPY"?